# How Create Session For Any Image Upload with Multiupload?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this code from: http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL

```
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
    }
```

I need Create Session for every image will be Upload for example :

```
$_SESSION['cropped_image1'] , $_SESSION['cropped_image2'] , $_SESSION['cropped_image3'] , ...
```

Sometime i need user 1 image upload and sometime more
I want send this session image to another php file.

any help?
best regards.

Comment: if you include session_start at both those php files the sessions will be accesible in both files, never tried storing an image in a session tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a for / foreach loop of somesort:

```
 $i = 0
 foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        $_SESSION['cropped_image_'.$i] = "your data";
        $i++
    }
```

Or you could make a session array

```
 foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        $_SESSION['cropped_image'][] = "your data";
    }
```

The first one stores the data in a seperate session per loop.
The second one stores it all in 1 session wich you could acces like so:

```
$_SESSION['cropped_image'][index];
```